# Cannot save and show data from angular polling factory function only with $scope

Tags: angularjs, controller, factory

I have a service with the following function below :

```
    (function(){

  angular.module('app.system')
  .factory('Poller', function($http, $timeout) {
        var data = {
            eventObj: null,
            spinner:false
          };

    var poller = function() {
      $http.get('php file').then(function(r) {
      var ev = r.data;

     if(ev.length > 0)
     {
        data.eventObj = ev;
        data.spinner  = true;

        if(ev.image != null && ev.image != "")
        {
          data.eventObj = ev;
        }
    }
    else {
      data.spinner  = false;
    }

        $timeout(poller, 1000);
      });

    };
    poller();

   return {
      data :data,
   };
```

})()

This was my factory. In controller I do something like :

```
    1     $scope.dataPoller = Poller.data;
    2     var vm = this;
    3    vm.event = Poller.data.event;
    4    vm.spinner = Poller.data.spinner;
```

also at top of controller :

.run(function(Poller) {});

line 1- I see the ui change every 500ms
but line 2-4 don't update at all - only at the beginning for example the vm.event always empty buy in line 1 it does not

How can I solve it?

I need to update the data in the controller or another service and return to controller and update the view  and the poller of course need to send new data every 500 ms

Comment: Please show your entire service code.

Comment: @AniketSinha  the  question has been updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vm.event = Poller.data.event;
vm.spinner = Poller.data.spinner;
```

This is executed once, when your controller is created. It nitialized `vm.event` with the value that Poller.data.event has **at this moment**. Same for the spinner. Since the view displays `vm.event`, and since that value never changes, your view never changes.

Instead, use

```
vm.pollerData = Poller.data;
```

and in the view, use

```
{{ vm.pollerData.event }}
```

Every time an $http response comes back, angular will reevaluate the value of `vm.pollerData.event`, and since the value has changed, the view will update.

Comment: thx. will check it ,

I need to take the data from poller - make a new list and make another object for preview mode, also handle the spinner.
where is the place to do all manipulation on data.?

Comment: I can't decipher this question.

Comment: Btw this is a goo approach to work with poller ?
at the end I need list with 20 result and in 500 ms new <li> should come and shown on the list - and the loader should appear until.
also part of the data is available and I Need to show it in preview mode

Comment: This is much too broad and too vague to be answered.

Comment: thx for answer it works 

if i have checkbox that markif the poller should run but keep the data that not in the list in "waiting" mode until the user will remove the checkbox , how can I pass the data in the opposite way from the view to the poller  during the regular run  ?

Comment: Do some research, then, if still stuck, ask another, separate question, with all the details needed to understand the problem, the required code, etc. This specific question has been answered.